# Multi label text classification from thousands of labels

Tags: multilabel-classification

I don't have machine learning experties, but I'm working on a project that has text classification requirements in it. The easiest approach I was able to understand was using fasttext.. It worked, but the accuracy is terrible. The problem is that we are trying to classify academic publications with multiple labels out of thousands of labels. I've followed all the best practices to clean the training data and followed the fasttext tutorials, but still the prediction quality is 15% max.

So my question is, is fasttext the right solution to this problem? What other solutions can be used if otherwise? Can you guide me to any examples or tutorials similar problems (multi-label out of VERY LARGE set of LABELS)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Data Science SE! Can you please provide additional details on your case? What kind of labels you are trying to predict, how you compute your "prediction quality" as 15%, what kind of performance you would like to reach? Withtout such details, I'm afraid you may not get accurate answers.

Comment: Thank you. The labels are terms from the FAST library (https://www.oclc.org/research/themes/data-science/fast.html).. We have thousands of already classified articles that I'm using as my training dataset. The way I'm computing the quality is through the model test method available in the fasttext library. I'm splitting my training data to 70% 30% training and validating and testing against that.

Comment: With so many labels it's not surprising that you get poor performance. What is the average number/size of document by label? Simple suggestion: as a first experiment you could simplify your data by removing any label which appears only a few times in the data, and try to improve progressively from there.